# Как запустить код js после scrollTo?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При клике на кнопку нужно проскролить к блоку `top-bar` и только после этого запустить остальную часть скрипта.
Как отследить это событие?

```js
$(".js-btn").on("click", function() {
  var barPosition = $(".top-bar").offset().top;

  window.scrollTo({
    top: barPosition,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
  $(".content").text("Scroll");
  });
```

```css
.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #eaeaea;
}

.top-bar {
  height: 40px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px 0;
}

.content {
  height: 500px;
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<header class="header"></header>
<div class="top-bar">
  <button type="button" class="btn js-btn">Click</button>
</div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая библиотека https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo и в ней событие **onAfter**

```js
$(".element").on("click", function () {
    jQuery.scrollTo('.target', 
    1600, 
    {
        onAfter:function(){ 
            alert("Конец анимации прокрутки");
        } 
    })
});
```

```css
section {
height: 80vh;
border-bottom: 20px solid orange;
}

.target {
height: auto;
padding: 30px;
text-align: center;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-scrollTo/2.1.2/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<section><span class="element">Click me</span></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section class="target">
Цель
</section>
<section></section>
```

Comment: А есть ли простой вариант без доп. плагинов или бибилиотек?

Comment: @E_K, посмотрите исходники библиотеки, достаньте нужные функции и напишите сами